# Small design problem with number of eligible voters on election page

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, election

The [election page](https://apple.stackexchange.com/election/) looks a little bit awkward, because the number of eligible voters is 'orphaned' on the previous line, at least for the first three elections:

[image]

The problem seems to be a missing `<br>`, which *is* included for the last election:

[image]

Comment: [Ask Different formatting bug in election page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225345/ask-different-formatting-bug-in-election-page)

Comment: Thanks George. It seems to have fallen off their radar. It shouldn't be too hard to fix, it's probably just updating some database entries.

Comment: I'm keeping the question here as well. It seems to be a site-specific bug; I've checked half a dozen other election pages.

Comment: @Oded Now [the flairs aren't side-by-side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECxaQ.png), is that another bug?

Comment: @grgarside - that's how it looks on most sites. I'd say that's by design (consider that for some sites, there may be more than 3 slots).

Comment: @Oded Great, thanks!

Comment: Thanks @Oded for fixing this!